# WPF C# - Bind Enum to ComboBox but don't use all enum values

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, enums

Let's say I have an enum that contains the properties:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    Yes, 
    No, 
    None
}
```

I can bind these values to a ComboBox pretty easily. However, let's say I want to omit the "None" value - what's the best way to go about this?

Comment: How do you populate `ItemSource`? Through some sort of converter? If yes then change that to omit `None`

Comment: you surely have to populate the items (using Reflection) with ***some codebehind***, so filtering out some value is just a trifle task.

Comment: Add all, then remove selected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Enum.GetValues()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues(v=vs.110).aspx) and then `Cast` to get an `IEnumerable`, then filter the results based on the ones you want to omit, e.g:

```
var items = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).Cast<MyEnum>()
                .Where(e => e != MyEnum.None);
```

Comment: Why `ToString()` and not just `e => e != MyEnum.None`?  Not really an issue here, but it's also good practice to append `ToList()` or `ToArray()` to any query that you use as an items source, or else you risk it being reevaluated.

Comment: No particular reason, I wrote this very quickly without a debugger but that should work too, the concept is still there and is simple enough to understand. Thanks for the tip.